# Tidy solutions to row-wise operations that meet a condition

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm stuck on how to develop a tidy solution that will look row-wise to see if a condition is met uniquely in each row.

Specifically, I have survey response data that use rating scales. The number of categories in the rating scale can vary by items. My data is in a wide format.

A sample of the data is below.

- In these data the column titled 'Item' indexes each survey item.
- Columns titled 'Cat_1' through 'Cat_5' are the rating scale categories across items. The values in these cells represent the percent of respondents endorsing a category of the rating scale. Item 1 has 5 valid categories in the rating scale, which is why values are present in the columns titled 'Cat_1 through 'Cat_5'. Item_2 has 4 rating scale categories possible. The NA in the 'Cat_5' for Item_2 is an indication of this not being a valid category of the rating scale for this item.
- The column titled 'Percent_missing' is the percent missing data for each item (supplied to mimic real-world application of data).
- The column titled 'flr_ceil' is the threshold value I want to use to see if either the first or last valid rating scale category for each item exceeds its threshold.

Ideally, I'd like to add a column that is called 'thresh_met', which is coded either 0/1 based on whether the first or last valid rating scale category for each item exceeds its threshold. For example, for 'Item_1' the value for 'thresh_met' would be 1 since Cat_1 == 33, which is greater than its threshold of 25. This is in contrast to Item_2 where the value for 'thresh_met' = 0 since neither the value of Cat_1 or Cat_4 exceed its threshold of 22.

The data look something like this:

```
Items  | Cat_1  |  Cat_2  |  Cat_3  |  Cat_4  |  Cat_5  |  Percent_missing | flr_ceil         |
Item_1 | 33     |  23     | 23      |  21     |  0      |   2              | 25               |
Item_2 | 20     |  30     | 20      |  10     |  NA     |   4              | 22               |
```

The code I have developed thus far is below. It should be clear where I am stuck. In this code the threshold that I want to use is marked as 'flr_ceil.'

Code:

```
# load packages and create data
if(!require("pacman"))install.packages("pacman")
p_load(tidyverse, magrittr, mice)

sample_dat <- tibble(
  Item_1 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1)),
  Item_2 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.4, 0.2, 0.05, 0.2, 0.15)),
  Item_3 = sample(0:5, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2)),
  Item_4 = sample(0:4, 100, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.6, 0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.05))) %>%
  mice::ampute(prop = .25) %$%
  amp

# get the valid number of categories for each item
col_names <- colnames(sample_dat) # for sorting at end of the pipe

cat_counts <-  sample_dat %>% 
  gather(key = Item, value = rating)  %>% 
  group_by(Item, rating) %>%
  summarise(
    n = n()) %>%
  group_by(Item) %>%
  summarise(
    flr_ceil = (1/n())*100
  ) %>%
  arrange(match(Item, col_names))

sample_dat %>% 
  gather(key = Item, value = rating)  %>% 
  group_by(Item, rating) %>%
  summarise(
    n = n()) %>%
  mutate(
    prop = (n/sum(n))*100
  ) %>%
  select(Item, rating, prop) %>%
  spread(rating, prop) %>%
  arrange(match(Item, col_names)) %>%
  left_join(cat_counts)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify -- it's not clear yet what your logic is here:  "flag any row where either the first or last valid rating scale category is >= some threshold in a new column (i.e., coded 0/1). In the case of the sample data above, Item_1 has 5 valid categories, while Item_2 has 4"... because ____ ?  It looks like Item_1 has 6 valid numbers following it, while Item_2 has 5.

Comment: @JonSpring Or maybe Item_1 has 6 valid numbers but Item_2 only has 4 before the `NA`. Anyway it's not clear how the valid categories are counted.

Comment: Thank you both. I have updated the question to provide more context for the data. Is this clearer?

Comment: I added more context. Thank you.

Comment: Overhauled for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below a tidyverse solution that might be helpful:

1. Convert the data (`df`) to long format with a single row for each `Item` and `Category`
2. Drop rows with `NA` values
3. Group by `Item` and arrange rows by `Category` name
4. Check if the first or last category value exceeds the threshold in `flr_ceil`

You can add the new column `thresh_met` back to `df` by a `join` or `mutate` call.

```r
library(tidyverse)

## df is generated using the code in the question
df
#> # A tibble: 4 x 8
#> # Groups:   Item [4]
#>   Item   Cat_1 Cat_2 Cat_3 Cat_4 Cat_5 Cat_6 flr_ceil
#>   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 Item_1    10    20    34   25      4    NA     16.7
#> 2 Item_2    43    15     5   23     11    NA     16.7
#> 3 Item_3    21    18     6   17     10    20     14.3
#> 4 Item_4    51    16    19    7.     2    NA     16.7

gather(df, key = "Category", value = "Value", starts_with("Cat")) %>%    
    na.omit() %>%                                                        
    group_by(Item) %>%                                                  
    arrange(Category) %>%                                               
    summarize(thresh_met = as.integer(any(Value[c(1, n())] > flr_ceil[c(1, n())])))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   Item   thresh_met
#>   <chr>       <int>
#> 1 Item_1          0
#> 2 Item_2          1
#> 3 Item_3          1
#> 4 Item_4          1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>